# IBM bluemix - NodeRED - failed to install node-red-contrib-chatbot

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red, chatbot

I'm trying to install [redbot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-chatbot) in Node-RED, on IBM Bluemix. As suggested [here](https://nodered.org/docs/platforms/bluemix), I'm using *Manage palette* to install it. I can find it in 'install' tab by typing *chatbot*. I click on *install* and then a pop up appears saying:

> Before installing, please read the node's documentation. Some nodes
>   have dependencies that cannot be automatically resolved and can
>   require a restart of Node-RED.

I click on install again, and after loading a little bit, it shows this message:

> Failed to install: node-red-contrib-chatbot Error: install failed
>   Check log for more information

And the debug tab shows this error message:

> Error: Command failed: npm install --production
>   node-red-contrib-chatbot

I tried to install dependences listed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-chatbot) following the same procedure described in this post, but some of them can't be found from *Manage palette*. I also tried restarting Node-red but without success.

Is there any alternative? How should I install this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can only install Node-RED nodes via the manage palette system, not the underlying npm nodes.

The best way to install Node-RED nodes that won't install cleanly via the manage palette option is to edit the Node-RED `package.json` The easiest way to do this is to go to the Overview page for the application console page in Bluemix. From  here click "Edit Code". From here you want to edit the package.json to include `node-red-contrib-chatbot` in the dependencies section.

```
"dependencies": {
  "node-red-contrib-chatbot": "0.7.1",
  ...
},
```

Once you've made the changes you will need to commit and push the changes, this should restart Node-RED and as part of this the node should be installed.

Comment: Sorry but I don't find  "Edit Code" buttom from [my overview panel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0bajMyYOyG4TnJINzZnZ1A4SVk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Edit code is in the bottom right hand corner, you may need to create a git repository first

Answer (score 0):

What hardililb says but if the issue is with all nodes - i.e. you cannot add any node, not even a simple one like random, via the Manage Palette, you can fix that.  Edit `bluemix_settings.js` and add:

```
var fs = require("fs");
```

Then after the `var settings=` section (not in it, after it), add:

```
   // Ensure userDir exists 
fs.mkdirSync(settings.userDir);
fs.mkdirSync(path.join(settings.userDir,"node_modules"));
```

Commit and Push.

Comment: I could install other nodes. However, I would like to check this file. Where is it?

Comment: same place as package.json

Comment: Thank you. For those who have no idea about how to find package.json (like me):  to edit the package.json, you need to enable the "Continuous Delivery" first, then the node-red starter code will be cloned to a git repository. Then you can find and edit the package.json via the git repository. Bluemix will pickup the latest codes from the repository, build and deploy it automatically.
You can find the "Continuous Delivery" from the "Overview" page of the app's dashboard.